# What is the purpose of `GPUImageFilterGroup`?

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage, imagefilter

What is the purpose of `GPUImageFilterGroup`?

Why do we need to do all the `addFilter`, `setInitialFilters`, `setTerminalFilter` steps? And we even need to `addTarget` for the filters in the group?
What's the difference between `filters` and `initialFilters` within `GPUImageFilterGroup.m`?

Is it possible that the `GPUImageFilterGroup` just receives a `filters` array, and set up `setInitialFilters`, `setTerminalFilter`, and even add target one by one for the filters being added?

```
        case GPUIMAGE_FILTERGROUP:
        {
            self.title = @"Filter Group";
            self.filterSettingsSlider.hidden = NO;

            [self.filterSettingsSlider setValue:0.05];
            [self.filterSettingsSlider setMinimumValue:0.0];
            [self.filterSettingsSlider setMaximumValue:0.3];

            filter = [[GPUImageFilterGroup alloc] init];

            GPUImageSepiaFilter *sepiaFilter = [[GPUImageSepiaFilter alloc] init];
            [(GPUImageFilterGroup *)filter addFilter:sepiaFilter];

            GPUImagePixellateFilter *pixellateFilter = [[GPUImagePixellateFilter alloc] init];
            [(GPUImageFilterGroup *)filter addFilter:pixellateFilter];

            [sepiaFilter addTarget:pixellateFilter];
            [(GPUImageFilterGroup *)filter setInitialFilters:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sepiaFilter]];
            [(GPUImageFilterGroup *)filter setTerminalFilter:pixellateFilter];
        }; break;
```

Comment: IMHO GPUImage is lacking some documentation, I found this article to provide a good intro when I used it : https://nshipster.com/gpuimage/ other than that I invite you to dive into the source code.

Comment: I agree with you, GPUImage is lacking some documentation. I could not understand the source code so well, I will try to do it better later then.